# What to do after a wrong RewriteRule?

Tags: jquery, htaccess, rewrite-rules, apache

I have A Wordpress MU and following [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16738394/4458531) I changed my root `.htaccess` placing this before the Wordpress loop `RewriteRule / /subfolder [R=301,L]` trying to have a different homepage.

It didn't work so I remove the line restart Apache, update the permalinks, but my homepage is now broken, I can access the dashboard from `example.com/wp-admin` directly, but there's no topbar on the frontpage.

From the JavaScript console seems that jQuery are not loaded, there are many `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <` but JQuery are loaded in the `function.php`.

Why this happened and what should I do in this situation?

Comment: It sounds like your browser caches the permanent (`R=301`) redirects. As .htaccess is evaluated on every request, a restart of apache is not necessary when changing something in the file. Try to clean your browser cache completely and reload the front page.

Comment: @David I clean the cache using W3 total cache, I opened in incognito mode a new window but still not luck...since everything pass through my CDN maybe I need to purge it

Comment: @David thank you very much! It seems all related to my CDN, after the purged it's now back to the normality